# Disable space in textbox (both typing spacebar and copy whitespace from other)

Tags: javascript, html, network-security

for prevent typing space code look like this (Javascript)

```
function RestrictSpace() {
  if (event.keyCode == 32) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

but it can't prevent paste whitespace
how to fix it?
thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HTML

```
<input type="text"onchange="myFunction(event)">
```

JS

```
 function myFunction(event) {
    console.log(event.target.value)
       event.target.value = event.target.value.replace(/\s/g, "");
    }
```

Comment: won't this mess up the cursor location while typing?